# Как правильно собрать production версию программы?

Tags: c++, windows

Пишу программу для windows(xp,7,8,10) с использованием Qt.

Рабочий ПК – Win10x64, в среде QtCreator с Qt5.8, MinGW 5.3.0 32bit.

Собираю программу в режиме релиз, добавляю к ней все необходимые библиотеки Qt. На моем ПК запускается нормально, все работает. На других ПК с Win10x64 тоже все хорошо.

Проблемы возникают, когда пытаюсь запустить на ПК c Win7x86. Иногда вылетают разного рода ошибки, в основном "не хватает библиотеки такой то (и различные системные библиотеки)", Иногда нет. О XP я вообще молчу, там вылетает постоянно.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом собрать программу таким образом, чтобы она работала на всех платформах?

Раньше никогда с таким не сталкивался, думал раз работает у меня то работает у всех.

Comment: Уточните, каким компилятором собран Qt? MinGW? MSVC?

Comment: @Abyx, Тогда как мне собрать релиз? Не переустанавливать же windows

Comment: x86 компилятор выбрать необходимо тебе, Мирон.

Comment: А разве х86 не значит что система 32 битная? Я уверен, что дело не в компиляторе, а скорее в правильной настройке сомой сборки.

Comment: 64-86 тут ни при чем, у вас под 32-битной ОС 64-битное приложение вообще не запустилось бы. Похоже, что вы собираете с какими-то функциями, специфичными для Win10 - появившиеся после Win7. Как минимум я бы начал с того, что делал бы все со статически линкуемыми библиотеками, а при компиляции где-то (не знаком с MinGW, так что не скажу, как) указал, что целевая ОС - Windows7. Чтобы и близко всякие функции из десятки не использовались. Но, кстати, именно так же надо собирать и Qt - иначе эти вызовы могут сидеть в ней...

Comment: @Harry Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы 64-разрядного приложения на 32-разрядной платформе x86 тут ни при чем, у вас под 32-битной ОС 64-битное приложение *вообще не запустилось бы*.

Похоже, что вы собираете свою программу с какими-то функциями, специфичными для Win10 - теми, которые появились уже после выхода Win7. При этом скомпоновано с динамическими библиотеками, которые подключаются по мере работы, только в тот момент, когда оказываются нужны.

Так что как минимум я бы начал с того, что собирал бы приложение со статически линкуемыми библиотеками, а при компиляции где-то (не знаком с MinGW, так что не скажу точно, как) указал, что целевая ОС - Windows7, чтобы никакие функции, специфичные для более поздних Windows не использовались.

Кстати, именно так же надо собирать и Qt, поскольку такие вызовы могут оказаться и в ней...

Вот конкретный пример, если хотите - функция [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) требует минимально Windows8. Программа с ней запросто скомпилируется, но вот работать в Windows7 не будет.

Есть и еще один момент - *не знаю, как он проявляется в MinGW, рассказываю о Visual C++* - при компоновке линковщик получает параметр `/SUBSYSTEM`, в котором указывается, с какой минимальной версией будет работать программа. Но этот ключик просто не позволяет запустить приложение, так что симптом не ваш, но тем не менее стоит о нем знать.